# How to move cube in trajectory in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I need to move a cube in trajectory motion using dots or arrow type symbol, when drag a mouse to move in a certain position of mouse and its drag power.

I used the code that was used in 2D project to move a ball in trajectory motion but it didn't work.

Here is the code what I tried so for

```
void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
    cubeClick = GameObject.Find("Cube Click Area");
    trajectoryDots = GameObject.Find("Trajectory Dots");
    rb = Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    trajectoryDots.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
        initialDotSize, 
        initialDotSize, 
        trajectoryDots.transform.localScale.z);
    for (int dotNumber = 0; dotNumber < 40; dotNumber++)
    {
        Dots[dotNumber] = GameObject.Find("Dot (" + dotNumber + ")");
        if (DotSprite !=null)
        {
            Dots[dotNumber].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = DotSprite;
        }
    }
    for (int dotNumber = NumberOfDots; dotNumber < 40; dotNumber++)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Dot (" + dotNumber + ")").SetActive(false);
    }
    trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);


}


void Update()
{
    Ray camRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    //RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(cam.(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
    if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out hit, 100f) && !cubeisClicked2)
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == Player.name)
        {
            cubeisClicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cubeisClicked = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cubeisClicked = false;
    }

    if (cubeisClicked2)
    {
        cubeisClicked = true;
    }

    if ((rb.velocity.x * rb.velocity.x) + (rb.velocity.y * rb.velocity.y) <= 0.0085f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    }
    else
    {
        trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);
    }
    cubePosition = Player.transform.position;
    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && cubeisClicked) && ((rb.velocity.x == 0f && rb.velocity.y == 0f)))
    {
        cubeisClicked2 = true;
        fingerPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        fingerPosition.z = 0f;
        cubeFingerDiff = cubePosition - fingerPosition;
        ShotForce = new Vector2(cubeFingerDiff.x * shootingPowerX , cubeFingerDiff.y * shootingPowerY);
        if (Mathf.Sqrt((cubeFingerDiff.x * cubeFingerDiff.x) + (cubeFingerDiff.y * cubeFingerDiff.y) )>0.4f)
        {
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);
        }

        for (int dotNumber = 0; dotNumber < NumberOfDots; dotNumber++)
        {
            x1 = cubePosition.x * ShotForce.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
            y1 = cubePosition.y * ShotForce.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift) - (-Physics.gravity.y / 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift) * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift));
            Dots[dotNumber].transform.position = new Vector3(x1, -y1, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            cubeisClicked2 = false;
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);

            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (ShotForce.x, ShotForce.y);;

        }


    }



}
```

It doesn't work, It shows the dots in as shown in the .

[image]

It should move the cube in a way the user drag and point to location to move.

Comment: what does it do instead of working? how is the result different from what you expect the code to do?

Comment: Please describe **how** it doesn't work

Comment: It does nothing other than creating dots when mouse clicked and the dots are created in wrong order as shown in the image

Comment: Where is the finger being pressed/dragging in the picture? I have no idea where the user is dragging and pointing, so I have no idea what the expected result in that case is supposed to be.

Comment: What do you have `ShootingPowerX` and `ShootingPowerY` set to be?  Also, what happens if you do `x1 = cubePosition.x + ShotForce.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
            y1 = cubePosition.y + ShotForce.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift) + (Physics.gravity.y / 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift) * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift));
            Dots[dotNumber].transform.position = new Vector3(x1, y1, 0);` (note the change from `cubePosition.xy *` to `cubePosition.xy +`)

Comment: "didn't work" makes it sound like it failed to compile. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: @Ruzihm It didn't work means it just shows the dots as shown in the above image, not able to move the dots with the help mouse left button pressed and drag, also didn't shoot the cube when release the button

Comment: You changed `cubePosition.x *` to `cubePosition.x +` and `cubePosition.y *` to `cubePosition.y +` and you still got the same result when clicking and dragging? Also, do you have `ShootingPowerX` or `ShootingPowerY` set to `0`?

Comment: @Ruzihm I changed the cubePosition.x * to cubePosition.x + and ShootingPowerX to 6 and ShootingPowerY to -1.5 it draws correctly but doesn't move with mouse movement and it doesn't jump on each mouse leave but some times it does

Comment: @EngrUmair I think I have figured it out. I want to know some details about what behavior you want.  Suppose the Cube is at `(0,0,0)` and the camera is at `(-1,0,0)`. I click on the cube and drag to the bottom left of the screen and let go. Should the cube then **1.** shoot up and to the right towards (1,1,0) or **2.** shoot up and to the backwards direction toward (0,1,-1) ? In other words, should the cube always have z=0 or should  it be able to be pushed in any direction depending on where the camera is?

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks, I need it should show where it is going to be shooted, while drawing the dots on that direction, when drag mouse down right it should go up and left (forward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is that using `cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` with a perspective camera always returns the position of the camera (this is a very common mistake), so instead of working with the mouse position vs the cube, you're working with the camera vs the cube.

You need to use another method to use the position of the mouse considering where the cube is compared to the camera.

One way to get the behavior you want is to create a plane running through the cube perpendicular to the direction of the camera, and to see where the mouse ray intersects with the plane. Also, set the `cubeisClicked2` flag to false, only setting it to true while we actually click on the plane:

```
cubePosition = Player.transform.position;
if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && cubeisClicked) && ((rb.velocity.x == 0f && rb.velocity.y == 0f)))
{
    cubeisClicked2 = false;

    Plane cubePlane = new Plane(cam.transform.position - cubePosition, cubePosition);

    // reusing camRay

    // Determine if we are even hitting the plane
    float enter = 0.0f;

    if (cubePlane.Raycast(camRay, out enter))
    {
        cubeisClicked2 = true;
        fingerPosition  = camRay.GetPoint(enter);
```

Also, you need to include z components in your force & trajectory calculations. You can probably just use shootingPowerX for the z component's power. There are also the changes that need to be made to the trajectory calculations that I mentioned in the comments:

```
        cubeFingerDiff = cubePosition - fingerPosition;
        ShotForce = new Vector3(cubeFingerDiff.x * shootingPowerX , cubeFingerDiff.y * shootingPowerY, cubeFingerDiff.z * shootingPowerX );
        if (cubeFingerDiff.magnitude>0.4f)
        {
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);
        }

        for (int dotNumber = 0; dotNumber < NumberOfDots; dotNumber++)
        {
            x1 = cubePosition.x + ShotForce.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
            y1 = cubePosition.y + ShotForce.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift) + (Physics.gravity.y / 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift) * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift));
            z1 = cubePosition.z + ShotForce.z * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
            Dots[dotNumber].transform.position = new Vector3(x1, y1, z1);
```

Then, instead of checking for `GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0)` in the same `if` as determining trajectory, it needs to be next to it and also check if a trajectory was found:

```
        }
    } 
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0) && cubeisClicked2)
{
    cubeisClicked2 = false;
    trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);

    rb.velocity = new Vector3 (ShotForce.x, ShotForce.y, ShotForce.z);;

}
```

Altogether, it might look like this:

```
cubePosition = Player.transform.position;
if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && cubeisClicked) && ((rb.velocity.x == 0f && rb.velocity.y == 0f)))
{
    cubeisClicked2 = false;
    Plane cubePlane = new Plane(cam.transform.position - cubePosition, cubePosition);

    // reusing camRay

    // Determine if we are even hitting the plane
    float enter = 0.0f;
    if (cubePlane.Raycast(camRay, out enter))
    {
        cubeisClicked2 = true;
        fingerPosition  = camRay.GetPoint(enter);

        cubeFingerDiff = cubePosition - fingerPosition;
        ShotForce = new Vector3(cubeFingerDiff.x * shootingPowerX , cubeFingerDiff.y * shootingPowerY, cubeFingerDiff.z * shootingPowerX );
        if (cubeFingerDiff.magnitude>0.4f)
        {
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);
        }

        for (int dotNumber = 0; dotNumber < NumberOfDots; dotNumber++)
        {
            x1 = cubePosition.x + ShotForce.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
            y1 = cubePosition.y + ShotForce.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift) + (Physics.gravity.y / 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift) * (DotSeparation * dotNumber + dotShift));
            z1 = cubePosition.z + ShotForce.z * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (DotSeparation * dotNumber * dotShift);
            Dots[dotNumber].transform.position = new Vector3(x1, y1, z1);
        }
    }         
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0) && cubeisClicked2)
{
    cubeisClicked2 = false;
    trajectoryDots.SetActive(false);

    rb.velocity = new Vector3 (ShotForce.x, ShotForce.y, ShotForce.z);;

}
```

Since this calculates the power of the shot on how far away on the `cubePlane`you're pointing at, when the camera is further away, you will be able to shoot  more strongly.

That is probably not the behavior you want, but if the camera is always kept at the same distance from the cube, it shouldn't be a problem.

If that's not an acceptable limitation, you can probably do something along the lines of dividing `ShotForce` by the distance between the cube and the camera and increasing `shootingPowerX` and `shootingPowerY` as necessary. If you can't find a good solution on your own, it would be best asked in a separate question.

Comment: Should I replace all of my code with your ones include the following :  Ray camRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    //RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(cam.(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
    and so on....

Comment: I think the rest of your code should work already, just replace everything in `Update` after & including `cubePosition = Player.transform.position;`

Comment: I did it, the dots now position it self according mouse but doesn't move the cube on leave

Comment: @EngrUmair I edited my answer to hopefully fix that. Try copying the whole thing again.

Comment: Thank you so much, it started working. One last thing I need to ask is I need to reset the dots to the original setup as it was before thrown and its position will always be near to cube.

Comment: @engrumair I don't understand. It might be better to make a new question with a screenshot of what is happening  and draw a picture of what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks once again, it helped a lot I will post a new question regarding trajectory path setting